# About the phalcon routes config ,is it the design bug?

Tags: url, routes, router, phalcon

```
$config = array(
    'best-url' => array(
        'pattern' => '/best',
        'paths' => array(
            'controller' => 'cate',
            'action' => 'index?cate_id=1',
        ),
    ),
    'better-url' => array(
        'pattern' => '/better',
        'paths' => array(
            'controller' => 'cate',
            'action' => 'index?cate_id=2',
        ),
    ),
    'cate-url' => array(
        'pattern' => '/cate/index/:int',
        'paths' => array(
            'controller' => 'cate',
            'action' => 'index',
            'cate_id' => '1'
        ),
    )
);
```

I have a requirement that ,the url map to the cate_id like /best -> /cate/index?cate_id=1,/better -> /cate/index?cate_id = 2,I don't know how to config my routes,I had solve it above,but I need it auto reverse routing when I use 
`$url->get('for'=>'cate-url','cate_id'=>1)`
it can not create the url like /best or /better.
        How can I solve it, thanks.

Comment: You can not pass parameters like this in action. Action is just action name. In 'best-url' just add 'cate_id' => '1' param to paths and so on.

Answer (score 0):

As @Arius said, the code should look like this, make sure you check the [routing the documentation](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/routing.html).

```
'best-url' => array(
    'pattern' => '/best',
    'paths' => array(
        'controller' => 'cate',
        'action' => 'index,
        'params' => array('cate_id'=>1)
    ),
)
```

Also, make sure you set your base uri:

```
$di->set('url', function(){
    $url = new Phalcon\Mvc\Url();
    $url->setBaseUri('/');
    return $url;
});
```

PS: I've never seen the way of configuring routes like you shown. Normally it's set like the following. I assume you iterate though the `$config` and add them like this somewhere in the code further down?

```
//Define a route
$router->add(
    "/best",
    array(
        'controller' => 'cate',
        'action' => 'index,
        'params' => array('cate_id'=>1)
    )
);
```